# как описывать типы данных структур, и их взаимодейтсиве

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность, файлы

У меня есть язык С++,но работаю в структурах как в си. У меня описана структура конфеты(цвет, вкус), конфет может быть н-количество. Хочу создать структуру коробка, коробок тоже н-количество, коробка как и в жизни может тоже вмещать себя н-количество конфет, и это количество конфет может естественно меняться. Список конфет описан в файле, думаю файл представляет из себя коробку. пример файла:
красная клубника
зеленая яблоко 
синий голубика 
Вопрос как описать структуру коробки, и нужна ли она вообще ?
в дальнейшем мне надо будет считать среднее количество конфет, именно в одной коробке, добавлять новое описание конфет, допустим отзыв о конфете, новые коробки, так же заполнение структур должно быть в разных потоках, что бы не висла программа.

Comment: Поскольку структура описания конфет у Вас одинаковая, отличаются только значения ее полей, сделайте коробку не структурой, а массивом. Будет удобнее обрабатывать конфеты.

Comment: Больше похоже на университетскую задачу, в реальности для таких задач используют СУБД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообше то экономические расчеты легче выполнять с помощью матриц. Вы, например, можете хранить матрицу с нулевыми значениями, где количество строк соответствует **количеству  цветов**, а количество столбцов _  **количеству вкусов**. Остается лишь присваивать  элементы по соответствующие индексам
`[цвет][вкус]`, потом выполнять нужные действия... (И цвет и вкус могут быть членами `enum`).

Но (не до конца известны ваши намерения) если этот подход не подходит под вашу задачу, можете определить класс (или пространство имен для функций и обьектов) записей, где можете определить что и как выполнять. Например:

```
class Records {
    //цвет, вкус
    using Candy = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
    //конфеты, количество 
    using Box = std::map<Candy, size_t>;    
public:
    /*добавить коробку с конфетами
    (сами решайте как поступят данные)*/
    void add([[maybe_unused]] std::istream& in)   { /*...*/ }

    // cчитать среднее количество конфет в n_ной коробке
    [[nodiscard]] double
    count_average(const size_t n) const noexcept {
        if (n < boxes.size()) {
            size_t sum = 0;
            for (const auto& p : boxes[n]) 
                sum += p.second;
            return  (double)sum / boxes[n].size();            
        }
        return 0;
    }
    //...
private:
    // все коробки сюда
    std::vector<Box> boxes;
};
```